# Prevent AWS Amplify From Adding Trailing Slash and Forcing Redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify and cannot figure out how to configure my rewrite and redirects or routes.js to prevent trailing slashes from breaking my functionality.

When I run my code locally and try to visit `localhost:3000/foo/bar/id` the page renders fine. When I deploy this same code through amplify and user clicks a button with an href, the browser gets a `302` and redirects the user to `example.com/foo/bar/id/`, then because this page doesn't exist, the default Amplify redirect sends them to `index.html` with a `404`

I have tried adding the following to my react routes:

```
/foo/bar/:id
/foo/bar/:id/
```

and the following redirect rules in the AWS Amplify console:

```
/foo/bar/<id>  | /foo/bar/<id> | 302
/foo/bar/<id>/ | /foo/bar/<id> | 302
```

but nothing is working. I am losing my mind here, any suggestions?

Answer (score 34):

Amplify adds a trailing slash to prevent urls like `/about.html` but that's probably not the real cause. Your app/browser is making requests to the server with routes that don't exist server-side (you're using SPA routes which are strictly client-side). Try adding the following redirect rule in the amplify js console (under App Settings: Redirects and rewrites > Edit > Open Text Editor):

```
[
    {
        "source": "</^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>",
        "target": "/",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

This rewrites all files to `/index.html` which is the only route that exists server-side. For more info, checkout the docs on [Trailing Slashes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#trailing-slashes-and-clean-urls) and [Redirects for SPAs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa).

Here is a picture about how to do this settings in the aws amplify:

[image: A picture that show aws amplify app settings]

It is better that we copy the JSON object in the provided text editor.

[image: A picture of text editor for JSON]

Otherwise if you are going to use the webform please take care that you must enter this string as source:

```
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>
```

the reason is webform will scape the backslashes!

Comment: It was really helpful. I will add a picture to your answer for clarification. I followed the solution and it resolved my issue.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me and resolved my issue. Whenever I loaded the website I developed in Chrome/Firefox on my phone, closed the app and re-opened it which reloads the last website, Amplify would give me an AccessDenied error...

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with my Next.js site on Amplify. After testing around for a few hours I've found the following solution:

```
[{
    "source": "/report/<slug>/",
    "target": "/report/<slug>",
    "status": "200",
    "condition": null
},
{
    "source": "/report/<slug>",
    "target": "/report/<slug>.html",
    "status": "200",
    "condition": null
}]
```

Add this to your redirects, then it should work.

You just have to replace "report" with your url parts.

Comment: Thank you for this! I've been looking all over the internet for this fix!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below one in the Rewrites & Redirect section worked for me as well. The trailing slash is now working.

```
[
    {
        "source": "</^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>",
        "target": "/",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

[image: The image attached below.. Mine is a React JS app hosted in amplify]